# excel numberformat pivotfield

Tags: c#, excel, pivot-table, number-formatting

Setting NumberFormat of a DateTime PivotField raises Exception, if at least one Value ist null.

We build an PivotTable from scratch in C# Code. One of the Worksheets holds the Data, the PivotTable resists on an other Worksheet. The code below works fine, if the Data has no null Values, but it raises an Exception when the Data has one or more null-Values.
The Exception is triggered when we write the pivotField.NumberFormat Property.

```
Excel.PivotField pivotField;
string sFieldName;

foreach (DataRow row in tblRowFields.Rows)
{
    sFieldName = doReportData.BuildDataFieldCaption(row);
    pivotField = pivotTable.PivotFields(sFieldName);
    pivotField.Orientation = Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlRowField;
    pivotField.Name = sFieldName;
    pivotField.Subtotals[1] = true;     // Teilergebnisse abschalten. Dafür ermal das mit Index 1 einschalten
    pivotField.Subtotals[1] = false;    // um danach das gleiche wirder auszuschalten.
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row["Field_DataType_ExcelFmt"].ToString()))
    {
        pivotField.NumberFormat = row["Field_DataType_ExcelFmt"].ToString();
    }
}
```

The (german) Text of the Exception is "Die NumberFormat-Eigenschaft des PivotField-Objektes kann nicht festgelegt werden", in english it will be sonething like "The numberformat-property of a PivotField-Object can not be defined"

Can someone confirm my suggestion or is there possibility to set the NumberFormat for PivotFields with null-Values?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  What is the exact text of the error you are receiving?

Comment: Hallo Derek, I've added the Exception Text to the Description.